# How to work around the ComboBox's auto complete

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, combobox

I'm using `ComboBox` with auto-complete that comes from a database table. The `Append` and `Suggest` is working perfect! And `AutoCompleteSource : ListItem`.

But I have a problem: when the user clicks on the arrow of the `ComboBox` and starts typing it starts to auto-complete normally, but if I press <kbd>Enter</kbd> it does not select the value I wanted.

I click on the `ComboBox` arrow and start typing a name and as it auto-completes the text in the `ComboBox` field, I hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> but it just jumps to the next control without setting that value to the `combobox`.

How do I select the desired value?

Comment: One possible workaround for this Bug is to disable autocomplete in a DropDown event handler and re-enable it in a DropDownClosed event handler.

Comment: @DJKRAZE Nothing man, I set the `AutoCompleteMode: NONE` on the properties of the `combobox`. And on the `DropDownClosed Event - AutoCompletMode: SuggestAppend"`. But still the same ;\

Comment: @DJKRAZE there's no such config, I've set `AutoCompletSource: ListItem`.

Comment: Yes I meant the Source sorry it was a typo

Comment: if you hit enter can you capture that information at the Key Event grabbing the e.Argument value as well as checking the Enter Key can you show the code in you key events..?

Answer (score 0):

You fix this in Javascript.  You need to tie into the box (probably on the key press event) and set it to keep a `var` pointing to the first value in the result set; and then on key press == 13 (enter), you want to set the element value to the previously stored `var`.  It's quick and easy to code.  You can make it even more fun to use by creating a custom control that wraps your other control, includes your custom JS, and extends properties such as "Required" for situations like this one.

Comment: ah, well, that means Javascript probably won't help you much ;-)  the key press event should still exist on your control, try attaching an event function there and look to see whether the eventArgs gives you enough to complete the selection.